# Angular4 Universal, how to upload to server?

Tags: angular

I just finished my angular4 website and now it's time for the seo part. I would like to make it 'Universal'.

I cloned the github seed at https://github.com/ng-seed/universal so i could play with it.

I found out that when i build it in the command promp with:

```
npm run build:universal-prod
```

It does finish succesfull but i wont get a dist file? how should i upload it to the server then?

With angular4 i just build it and ship the dist file on FileZilla.

Comment: Uhm.. where are you hosting it at? What you will build with Angular Universal will be your server. Are you hosting on something that runs on Apache?

Comment: I am using this hosting provider: www.starthosting.nl. Where should I host it? I think they use apache but i don't know for sure..

Comment: if you want to use Angular Universal you MUST use a hosting service that doesn't provide a server out of the box. Examples are Heroku and DigitalOcean. The former uses just a build process (you need to know how to use git), the latter you need to install even the operating system itself. You can easily find guides about them.

Comment: btw that seed is chaotic as hell, I suggest you to use official [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) paired with [the official documentation about Universal](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/universal.html). Or a [seed](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) ready out of the box, but that uses Angular 2

Comment: thanks for the advice! I stumbled upon this seed as well: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal. would that be a better starting point?

Comment: I think that it would be overloaded of things, when you start to learn something new, start simple :)

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem dude!